# Какими плагинами сейчас пользуются для wordpress

Tags: wordpress, плагин

Всем привет! Я новичок в мире wordpress(знаю только ModX).

Хотелось бы узнать какими плагинами сейчас пользуются разработчики. Например, при создании multilang сайта с custom-ным шаблоном.

Для работы с options советуют Redux.
Шаблоны советуют создавать custom-но или page builder-ом "Qoob"
Про multilang еще ничего не советовали.

Не знаю как использовать эти плагины в multilang сайте.

Прошу вас посоветовать какие плагины взять для использования: чтоб были легки в обучении и удобны при использовании. Думаю, у разрабов если плагины, которые они используют в каждых своих проектах.

Comment: Советы, вам выданные, находятся далеко от WordPress mainstream. Для опций у WP есть свой API. Про Qoob я никогда не слышал, при наличии некоторого опыта) Плагинов для WP только в официальном репозитории более 50 тыс. Поэтому ни о каком "джентльменском наборе" речи нет. Многоязычность обеспечивается плагинами, их немного, в силу сложности.

Comment: Самый мощный плагин для многоязычности - WPML, он платный. Если можно назвать платой 39 долл в год. Из бесплатных заслуживает внимания Polylang

Answer (score -1):

Для multilang. Сайта  могу посоветовать платный weglot - перевод хороший и ничего на сайте хранить не надо, front end переводится автоматически. Еще есть WPML и Polylang как и советовали в комментариях.